# Stopping Kendo grid refresh/update wheel image

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo-grid which refreshes very frequently but the update wheel that keeps appearing over the grid (on every refresh) looks so annoying i just want to turn this off how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#someElementId"), false)
```

to hide it.

Comment: You are superstar :) Thanks a lot

Comment: With Firefox it still seems to show the wheel .. with chrome its alright now

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: Which OS, Firefox version and Kendo release are you using? It works for me :-(

Comment: I am having such problems with firefox before like variables remaining undefined even though in chrome they are showing proper values etc. am using firefox 18.0 . windows 7 kendo release 2012.3.1114...

Comment: I've just tested your same configuration and it worked! The only question that I've seen (but also for Chrome) is that I need to set `progress` to `false` each time a send a request to the server. Ex: of my `transport.read` is `transport : { read: { url: function() { kendo.ui.progress($("#grid"), false); return "data.jsp"; } } },`

Comment: i moved the line of code way down in my jscript file and it worked on firefox as well.. Thanks a lot for all ur help